# After moving a Django application to a new project on the same server it is still using the original project settings.py

Tags: nginx, python, django

Setup: Django version 1.4, using Supervisor, NGINX, gunicorn, and postgresql 8.4.

I have two Django projects hosted on one server, and one is leaving the server. There is an important application that needs to remain on this server temporarily while I rebuild it in an entirely new framework on the new server. I want to attach it and its data to the new project. I copied all of the application files/templates to the new application, added it to `settings.py`, and ran `manage.py syncdb`. I used PGAdmin's backup/restore functions to move the data to the new database. When I log into the Django admin site everything looks proper: the models are all there on the new project and all of the data seems intact.

I also had to make changes to my nameserver to allow for a subdomain redirect like so:

subdomain.mysite.com ANAME points to my IP for the new project, which has a different domain:

my_other_site.com

My NGINX conf for my_other_site.com listens for subdomain.mysite.com and redirects it to

my_other_site.com/relevant_app_url

Now the problem: the new urls seem to work fine, but it is using the old project's `.py` files and templates. I even commented out the app in the settings files of both new and old projects and all it did was hide the admin site from me.

To identify the problem I inserted a typo into the old project `views.py`, and got it to throw a traceback, which let me see that it was using the old project's `settings.py` instead of the new one. How do I make the app switch to the new project `settings.py`? How is it even finding the old one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in my NGINX conf file:

I copied the location of the application, unchanged, to the new project conf:

```
server {
    listen    80;
    server_name  www.my_other_site.com;
    ...
    other stuff not relevant to this answer here
    ...

    location /relevant_app_url/ {
        ...
        other stuff not relevant to this answer here
        ...
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000

    }
}
```

8000 refers to the original project on the server. 8001 is the port for the other project (where my application now lives). I had to change the last line to:

`proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001`

And all is well. Hope my frustration makes for a quick solution to someone else having a slow moment.